# mongod run with nohup exits when there is no open connection

Tags: mongodb, database

I am running `mongod` on `nohup` as

`nohup mongod -dbpath /data/db > log/nohup.log &`

Server runs for some time but closes with following log

```
2015-08-24T20:23:12.076+0000 I NETWORK  [conn74] end connection 127.0.0.1:51016 (0 connections now open)
2015-08-24T20:23:57.112+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51019 #75 (1 connection now open)
2015-08-24T20:23:57.118+0000 I NETWORK  [conn75] end connection 127.0.0.1:51019 (0 connections now open)
2015-08-24T20:24:56.026+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] got signal 1 (Hangup), will terminate after current cmd ends
2015-08-24T20:24:56.026+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] now exiting
2015-08-24T20:24:56.026+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-08-24T20:24:56.026+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 5
2015-08-24T20:24:56.026+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] closing listening socket: 6
2015-08-24T20:24:56.026+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2015-08-24T20:24:56.026+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-08-24T20:24:56.026+0000 I NETWORK  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-08-24T20:24:56.026+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2015-08-24T20:24:56.026+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: final commit...
2015-08-24T20:24:56.026+0000 I JOURNAL  [signalProcessingThread] journalCleanup...
2015-08-24T20:24:56.027+0000 I JOURNAL  [signalProcessingThread] removeJournalFiles
2015-08-24T20:24:56.045+0000 I JOURNAL  [signalProcessingThread] Terminating durability thread ...
2015-08-24T20:24:56.129+0000 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread stopped
2015-08-24T20:24:56.129+0000 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread stopped
2015-08-24T20:24:56.129+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: closing all files...
2015-08-24T20:24:56.132+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] closeAllFiles() finished
2015-08-24T20:24:56.132+0000 I STORAGE  [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2015-08-24T20:24:56.132+0000 I CONTROL  [signalProcessingThread] dbexit:  rc: 0
```

Any idea about how to make `mongod` continuously running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer is simple and it's to start mongod as a deamon by using `--fork`

`mongod --fork --logpath log/mongod.log`

[mongodb documents](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#start-mongod-as-a-daemon)

Comment: even using `disown` after the original command helped. This answer `http://askubuntu.com/questions/611968/differences-between-command-disown-and-nohup-command-disown#answer-612106` says both `nohup` and `disown` serves the same purpose and don't need to be used both at a time still it helped.